# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

i cannot get value $list_izin from array, how can i get value from array and set the value for where clause condition

$list_izin = ['7','11','14','16','19','202','139','157'];

```
$where = array(
    'tmuser_userauth.userauth_id' => $userauth_id,
    'tmpegawai.bidangid' => $bidangid,
    'trperizinan_user.trperizinan_id' => $list_izin
    );
    }
    return $this->db
            ->select('
                tmpegawai.pegawaiid,
                tmpegawai.n_pegawai,
                tmpegawai.telp,
                tmuser.photo,
                tmuser.last_login,
                trperizinan_user.trperizinan_id

            ')
            ->from($this->table)
            ->join('tmuser', 'tmuser.tmpegawai_id = tmpegawai.pegawaiid')
            ->join('tmuser_userauth','tmuser_userauth.tmuser_id = tmuser.id')
            ->join('trperizinan_user','trperizinan_user.user_id = tmuser.id')
            ->where($where)
            ->get();
}
```

Comment: Use `where_in()` or `or_where_in()`.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that duplicate only partially applies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the "unknown column 'Array'" error because the array of IDs is being converted to a string when that value of the associative array is processed by `where()`. ("Array" is the string representation of any array in PHP.)

To fix it, first remove that last column from the `$where` array.

```
$where = array(
    'tmuser_userauth.userauth_id' => $userauth_id,
    'tmpegawai.bidangid' => $bidangid,
);
```

Then in your select query add the list of IDs in a `where_in()` condition.

```
return $this->db
    ->select('
        tmpegawai.pegawaiid,
        tmpegawai.n_pegawai,
        tmpegawai.telp,
        tmuser.photo,
        tmuser.last_login,
        trperizinan_user.trperizinan_id

    ')
    ->from($this->table)
    ->join('tmuser', 'tmuser.tmpegawai_id = tmpegawai.pegawaiid')
    ->join('tmuser_userauth','tmuser_userauth.tmuser_id = tmuser.id')
    ->join('trperizinan_user','trperizinan_user.user_id = tmuser.id')
    ->where($where)
    ->where_in('trperizinan_user.trperizinan_id', $list_izin)
    ->get();
```

The `where_in()` will be added to the existing criteria defined in the `where()`, it won't replace it.